# IE11ではShowModalDialogしたウインドウでのonKeyDownイベントでF12が拾えない

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptでF12を制御して、無効化にしたいですが、IE11ではShowModalDialogしたウインドウでのonKeyDownイベントでF12が拾えない。IE10以前の開発ツールが起動してしまいます。